# C# WPF DataGrid doesn't show decimal from SQLite 3 database

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I ran into an issue with C# WPF, where I want to show some SQLite data table in WPF DataGrid control. We store the price of a product as a NUMERIC (but also tried as REAL, but it does the very same), but in the datagrid control it is shown as integer, despite on the SQLite DB Browser it shows the proper decimal value. Here is the code with which we fill in the data into the DataGrid:

```
ProductsDataGrid.ItemsSource = db.GetDataSet("*", "products").Tables[0].AsDataView();
```

and the GetDataSet method looks like this:

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string columns, string table, string trailingCommands = "")
{
    var sqlcmd = string.Format("select {0} from {1} {2}", columns, table, trailingCommands);
    Utility.Log.Info(sqlcmd);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlcmd, this.dbconn);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    return dataSet;
}
```

Short version:
The program shows decimal numbers as int in a datagrid from SQLite DB

Comment: Can you include the view where you use the datagrid in your post? Or do you add the datagrid also programmatically? If so, please add this, too.

Comment: please specify more which part, because I can add additional sources I just don't want to clutter everything with not-to-the-point sources

Comment: the datagrid itself is done in XAML and basically this is it:       <DataGrid x:Name="ProductsDataGrid" Margin="0,0,10,0" CellEditEnding="CategoryDataGrid_CellEditEnding" AutoGeneratedColumns="ProductsDataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns"/>

Comment: From what I read here: [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm)  there is no data class NUMERIC only a type affinity that is named that way. Can you make sure both the data class and the type affinity is set to a value supporting decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your SQLite decimal separator character, that's could be it.

Comment: you are in fact very right, that was the issue! Thanks man! You're golden!