# C# ASCX Module DataGrid doesn’t show values to 2 decimal places from MySQL-Workbench database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql-workbench

I have a collection of data in a MySQL database table that I am trying to display in a DataGrid in an ascx module using C#. The values in the database table are stored as a float. I am running into a problem when I display the data from the database table into my DataGrid ( i.e. if the value in the database is 3.30, my DataGrid is showing it as 3.3). I would like to have the values in the DataGrid be shown to 2 decimal places. If the database table shows the value 3.00, I want that same value to be displayed in my DataGrid table as well.

I have done quite an extensive search online and here on stackoverflow. I did find a few similar questions like [C# WPF DataGrid doesn't show decimal from SQLite 3 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979343/c-sharp-wpf-datagrid-doesnt-show-decimal-from-sqlite-3-database), but it was not helpful for what I was trying to do.

Below is my code to my ascx and ascx.cs. Any help in solving this will be greatly appreciated.

**ascx code**

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="MyDataGrid2" Width="50%" BorderColor="Black" ShowFooter="false" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#81DAF5" HorizontalAlign="Left" EnableViewState="false" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
    <ItemStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Score" HeaderText="Score TEST" DataFormatString="{0:C}"></asp:BoundColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

**ascx.cs code**

```
protected static DataTable Pivot1(DataTable tbl)
{
    var tblPivot = new DataTable();
    tblPivot.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(String));
    for (int col = 0; col < tbl.Columns.Count; col++)
    {
        var r = tblPivot.NewRow();
        r[0] = tbl.Columns[col].ToString();
        for (int j = 0; j < tbl.Rows.Count; j++)
        r[j] = tbl.Rows[j][col];
        tblPivot.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    return tblPivot;
}

protected void GroupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OdbcConnection dbConnection2 = new OdbcConnection(srlsConnStr))
    {
        dbConnection2.Open();                
        OdbcCommand dbCommand5 = new OdbcCommand();
        dbCommand5.Connection = dbConnection2;
        dbCommand5.CommandText = string.Format(@"SELECT TRUNCATE(AVG(s.srls_c1), 2) AS c1_total,
                TRUNCATE(AVG(s.srls_c2), 2) AS c2_total,
                TRUNCATE(AVG(s.srls_c3), 2) AS c3_total,
                TRUNCATE(AVG(s.srls_c4), 2) AS c4_total,
                TRUNCATE(AVG(s.srls_c5), 2) AS c5_total,
                TRUNCATE(AVG(s.srls_c6), 2) AS c6_total,
                TRUNCATE(AVG(s.srls_c7), 2) AS c7_total,
                TRUNCATE(AVG(s.srls_c8), 2) AS c8_total
            FROM srlsvouchergroup g
            JOIN srlsvouchers v ON v.voucher_group_voucher_group_id = g.group_id_pk
            AND v.voucher_status = 'Taken'
            JOIN srlssurvey s ON s.voucher_no = v.Voucher_no_pk
            WHERE g.group_name = ?;");

        dbCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group_name", inst_group_name);
        OdbcDataReader dataReader5 = dbCommand5.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
        dt7.Load(dataReader5);
        DataTable dt8 = Pivot1(dt7);

        MyDataGrid_2.DataSource = dt8;
        MyDataGrid_2.DataBind();

        dataReader5.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using the wrong `DataFormatString` value... The below should get you going.

`DataFormatString="{0:0.00}"`

You can see more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

**UPDATE**

Looks like it's probably to do with your `.ToString();` which does not implement `IFormattable`.

Use `string.Format(...)` seen below, this will give you your desired results:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double test = 3.00;
    Console.WriteLine("number: " + test);

    Console.WriteLine("new number: " + string.Format("{0:0.00}", test));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**output:**

```
number: 3
new number: 3.00
```

So, your problem appears to be with this line, which automatically truncates the 0's before it's sent to the grid:

```
r[0] = tbl.Columns[col].ToString();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't do anything, the value is still showing up as 3 instead of 3.00 like I want. Is there a way I can force the zeros to show up on the screen so that 3 is forced to display 3.00?

Comment: Well, what happens when you step through your code? What does `r[0] = tbl.Columns[col].ToString();` look like after that line executes? The code above definitely keeps two decimals on a float, double, etc that comes out of a database, and I was just able to confirm that (with a value of 3.00). That could also very well be your culprit.

Comment: I got it working. I had to change `r[0] = tbl.Columns[col].ToString();` to `r[0] = tbl.Columns[col].ReadOnly;` which then showed the values to 2 decimal values.

Comment: @skaur If you remove `.ReadOnly` it will work too. It's just the `.ToString()` part that removes them.

Comment: that solution may work for someone else but when I tried it in my application it threw me an error. So it seems in my case I need to use the `.ReadOnly` but thank you for your help, it really helped me solve my problem.